# Review edit leads to question?

Tags: bug, review, edits, suggested-edits

I was in the review queue ([First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts)) and decided to suggest an edit for the current item. After submitting the edit, I was redirected to that question instead of going back into the review.

Is this the proper functionality?  I have not reviewed anything for a while, but the last I remember edits sent you back to the review item.

If it makes a difference, it was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21938577/1618257) on [this review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/4332846).

**Update**
Turns out it was a test. Perhaps edits on a test question are the issue?

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  The Q/A and Review systems are separate, and don't have much awareness of each other.  In particular, the Review System doesn't put a ReturnURL on the URL when sending you to the Suggested Edit screen.  The remedy is to click on the Review link again; you should arrive at the same place you were.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But if I was in the review que, then after suggesting an edit I would think I should go back to the review item to hit "I'm Done" and move on to the next item.